# Multiple RadioButtons Simulator

Tags: jframe, radio-button, simulator

I'm trying to make a sort of simple soccer simulator. This is the code I created after watching tutorials and i know its pretty bad. All i want to do is add a value to the team, like 1 for the best team and 10 for the worst, and when i click simulate a pop up would show up telling me which team would win given the teams value. But i cant figure out how to do it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;



public class sim extends JPanel {

  public sim() {
    // JFrame constructor
      super(true);

    JRadioButton chelsea, arsenal, chelsea2, arsenal2;

    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,0));

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    ButtonGroup group2 = new ButtonGroup();

    // takes image and saves it the the variable
    Icon a = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("a.PNG"));
    Icon c = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("c.JPG"));


    chelsea = new JRadioButton("Chelsea",c);
    chelsea.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    chelsea.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);

    arsenal = new JRadioButton("Arsenal",a);
    arsenal.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    arsenal.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);

    group.add(chelsea);
    group.add(arsenal);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("");
    TitledBorder titled = new TitledBorder("Team 1");
    label.setBorder(titled);

    chelsea.setBorder(titled);
    arsenal.setBorder(titled);

    JButton button = new JButton("Simulate");
    button.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
    add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    chelsea2 = new JRadioButton("Chelsea",c);
    chelsea2.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    chelsea2.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);

    arsenal2 = new JRadioButton("Arsenal",a);
    arsenal2.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    arsenal2.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);

    group2.add(chelsea2);
    group2.add(arsenal2);

    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("");
    TitledBorder titled2 = new TitledBorder("Team 2");
    label2.setBorder(titled2);

    chelsea2.setBorder(titled);
    arsenal2.setBorder(titled);

    add(label);
    add(chelsea);
    add(arsenal);

    add(button);

    add(chelsea2);
    add(arsenal2);

    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    chelsea.addActionListener(handler);
  }

  private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener
  {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {

          //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("%s", e.getActionCommand()));

      }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Final");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
    frame.setContentPane(new sim());
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `ActionListener` into the sim class.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JButton clicked = (JButton)e.getSource();
        if(clicked == button)
        {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "this team will win");
        }
     }
```

You need to decrees the amount of code to just amount needed you dont need to show us all the raidio

Comment: ok i did that, but how would i be able to click a team in one group and the team in the other then the simulate button to then show the result?

Comment: Simulate Results? what would Happed How would you simulate results? `x>y`?

Comment: When the two teams are picked how would i make it  when i clicked the sim button the team with the better value would print?

Comment: `if(higherValue > otherTeam)` `{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,higherValue);}`                       `else if(higherValue < otherTeam)` `{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,otherTeam);}`